# How to change QGraphicsPixmapItem visibility after its animation is finished?

Tags: qt4, visibility, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm animating position and opacity of QGraphicsPixmapItem subclass using QPropertyAnimation. After pixmap becomes fully transparent I want to hide it using setVisible(false); or hide(); to block its mouse events. I tried to use QPropertyAnimation, but it looks like that animation doesn't change boolean properties. What is the other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

QPropertyAnimation emits a [`finished()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractanimation.html#finished) signal when it's done animating your object. Hook it up to a slot in your controlling object to hide the item.